# EPPlus Stored Procedure to Excel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, epplus

Please, give me an opinion, how to make automated table with headers (row1)?
I took some of teh code from the Internet, and I adjusted to my needs..

Is tehre a part of a code which I can get automated creation of a table?

I wrote this:

```
 public void GetExcel()
    {
        StatusPipelineMerge merge = new StatusPipelineMerge();

        var list = merge.Procedure1();
        using (var excelPackage = new ExcelPackage())
        {
            excelPackage.Workbook.Properties.Author = "Web App";
            excelPackage.Workbook.Properties.Title = "Export from the Web";
            var sheet = excelPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Export Results");
            // output a line for the headers
            //CreateHeader(sheet);
            sheet.Name = "export results";
            // all indexes start at 1
            var rowIndex = 2;
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                var col = 1;
                sheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = "Client Name";
                sheet.Cells[1, 2].Value = "Field of Cooperation";
                sheet.Cells[1, 3].Value = "Project Value HR";
                sheet.Cells[1, 4].Value = "Project Value Money (EUR)";
                sheet.Cells[1, 5].Value = "Comment";
                sheet.Cells[1, 6].Value = "Sales Responsible";
                sheet.Cells[1, 7].Value = "Created Date";
                sheet.Cells[1, 8].Value = "Modified Date";
                sheet.Cells[1, 9].Value = "Status";

                sheet.Cells[rowIndex, col++].Value = item.ClientName;
                sheet.Cells[rowIndex, col++].Value = item.NameFCO;
                sheet.Cells[rowIndex, col++].Value = item.ProjectValueHr;
                sheet.Cells[rowIndex, col++].Value = item.ProjectValueMoney;
                sheet.Cells[rowIndex, col++].Value = item.CommentPipeline;
                sheet.Cells[rowIndex, col++].Value = item.Name+" "+item.Surname;
                sheet.Cells[rowIndex, col++].Value = item.CreatedTimeSTamp;
                sheet.Cells[rowIndex, col++].Value = item.ModifiedTimeStamp;
                sheet.Cells[rowIndex, col++].Value = item.JobStatusName;
                rowIndex++;
            }
            sheet.Column(3).Style.Numberformat.Format = "$#,##0.00";
            sheet.Column(4).Style.Numberformat.Format = "$#,##0.00";
            // You could just save on ExcelPackage here but we need it in
            // memory to stream it back to the browser
            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.BinaryWrite(excelPackage.GetAsByteArray());
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
                      "attachment;filename=results.xlsx");
            Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

So, I just need to wrap it in table with headers/filters. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the data from a stored proc, why not use a `DataTable` and the function `LoadFromDataTable()`?  There are plenty of examples, here is one:

[EPPlus LoadFromDataTable() is double escaping ampersands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569450/epplus-loadfromdatatable-is-double-escaping-ampersands)

Keep in mind if it is a very BIG table there is a performance penalty with that function and you are better sticking with what you are doing with `for` loops.

Another option would be using `LoadFromCollection` which has the options to print headers as well:

[Use 'LoadfromCollection' with a list containing another list inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33825995/use-loadfromcollection-with-a-list-containing-another-list-inside)